# Wagtail Add to context from abstract subclass

Tags: wagtail

I'm making a reusable wagtail app for managing Team Members via a `TeamMember` model.

What I want is to install this app and then have an easy way to add team members to the context of pages without having to write a `get_context` function on each page model.

In the app I've added an abstract django model with a `get_context` function:

```
class TeamPageExtension(models.Model):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['team'] = TeamMember.objects.all()
        return context

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

On the website..

```
class DummyTeamPage(Page, TeamPageExtension):
    template = 'home/team_page.html'
```

This doesn't work. I can see that calling super() in TeamPageExtension's `get_context` isn't going to work but can't think of another way to do this.

What I want is for the `team` variable to be added to the context of any page model "extended" with TeamPageExtension.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried putting `TeamPageExtension` before `Page` in `DummyTeamPage`'s parent list? (Also, I don't think you need `TeamPageExtension` to inherit from `models.Model` in this case.)

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to gasman for the solution:

In the app:

```
class TeamPageExtension():
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['team'] = TeamMember.objects.all()
        return context
```

In the wagtail site:

```
class AnotherExtension():
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['alex'] = 'noob'
        return context

class DummyTeamPage(TeamPageExtension, AnotherExtension, Page):
    # Both 'team' and 'alex' are available in the template context
    template = 'home/team_page.html'
```